# Neo4j/Cypher: Count distinct node combinations that match a pattern

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I query paths within a Neo4j graph. The path contains more than two nodes. I want to count the distinct occurences of a two-node subpath.

So in the following example I want to know the number of the resulting rows:

```
MATCH ()-->(n1:Label1)-->(n2:Label2)-->()
RETURN DISTINCT n1, n2
```

E.g. something like

```
RETURN count(DISTINCT n1, n2)
```

(which would work for a single node: `RETURN count(DISTINCT n1)`)

How can I do this in Cypher?

Comment: can u explain Label1 and Label2? example- People connected to City nodes?

Comment: An Example could be: `(:City)<-[:LIVES_IN]-(n1:Person)-[:KNOWS]->(n2:Person)-[:LIVES-IN]->(:City)` I am looking for a query that answers the question: How many unique (`n1`, `n2`)-tuples do exist that match the pattern above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this to get the number of times each distinct `n1` and `n2` combination is found:

```
MATCH ()-->(n1:Label1)-->(n2:Label2)-->()
RETURN n1, n2, COUNT(*);
```

[Aggregating functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/functions/aggregating/) like `COUNT` use non-aggregating items in the same `WITH` or `RETURN` clause as unique "grouping keys" (so no need to use `DISTINCT`).

[UPDATE]

To get the number of distinct `n1` and `n2` combinations, you can aggregate twice in this somewhat hacky query:

```
MATCH ()-->(n1:Label1)-->(n2:Label2)-->()
WITH n1, n2, COUNT(*) AS ignored
RETURN COUNT(*) AS nCombos;
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! This code snippet generates a table with one row for each unique `n1, n2` combination and counts the occurrences of the different combinations in the `count(*)` column. I'm, however, interested in the single number that counts the unique `n1, n2` combinations, hence the number of rows in your suggestion.